# How can i add more than 1mission

Tags: java

I have a problem I want to make an app make more than 1 mission but it makes just 1 mission.
Note that `Mission` is a class and 
`toManinActivity` is an ArrayList. How can I solve it?

```
   Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Name.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Name.setError("");
                } else if (Hours.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Hours.setError("");
                } else if (Minutes.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Minutes.setError("");
                } else if (AboutMission.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    AboutMission.setError("");
                } else {
                    int h = Integer.parseInt(Hours.getText().toString());//The hours
                    int m = Integer.parseInt(Minutes.getText().toString());//The minutes
                    if (m >= 60) {
                        Minutes.setError("Minutes should be under 60");
                    } else if (h >= 12) {
                        Hours.setError("Hours should be under 12");
                    } else {                        
                        toMainActivity.add(0, new NewMission("Date" + ":" + Dates, "Name" + ":" + Name.getText().toString(), "TIme" + ":" + Hours.getText().toString() + ":" + Minutes.getText().toString() + AmPm.getSelectedItem().toString(), "About Mission" + ":" + AboutMission.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(importance.getSelectedItem().toString())));
                        PreferencesManager.getInstance(Main2Activity.this).putString("Name", new Gson().toJson(toMainActivity));
                        startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your mission object to the first (0) index of your list meaning you will overwrite anything that was already at that index (0). Use basic `add()` method without an index parameter so that each new object is added at the end of the list.

```
toMainActivity.add(new NewMission...
```